# How can I Extract only numbers from this columns By Index of column?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have the same problem [How can I Extract only numbers from this columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800443/how-can-i-extract-only-numbers-from-this-columns)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
         {'SELECTIO':['N NO',37002,37003,'Krishan',37004,'singh',37005],
          'some_col':[4,6,14,26,38,47,60]}
)
print(df)

# Output
  SELECTIO  some_col
0     N NO         4
1    37002         6
2    37003        14
3  Krishan        26
4    37004        38
5    singh        47
6    37005        60
```

but the problem is that I want get the result by column index
I tried this `df[df[[0]].apply(lambda x: x[0].isdigit(), axis=1)]`
but it showing me error

`KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: use same the above solved question df

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to numeric and filter non missing values in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 0], errors='coerce').notna()]
```

Your solution with [`Series.str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) and casting to strings:

```
df[df.iloc[:, 0].astype(str).str.isdigit()]
```

Comment: thanks for answering but it working on small data . When I put large data that line gives error
IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: @HabibUrRehman - Can you try `df[pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 0], errors='coerce').notna().to_numpy()]` ?

Comment: it also gives the same error
IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: @HabibUrRehman - Is possible see your complete code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.iloc` to select the first column and `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` parameter then drop `NaN` rows:

```
>>> df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 0], errors='coerce').dropna().index]
  SELECTIO  some_col
1    37002         6
2    37003        14
4    37004        38
6    37005        60
```

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'SELECTIO':['N NO',37002,37003,'Krishan',37004,'singh',37005], 'some_col':[4,6,14,26,38,47,60]})
this is df
when I tried your code 
df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df[1], errors='coerce').dropna().index]
it gives me error

Comment: You want to extract numeric values from columns 'SELECTIO' and keep rows, right?

Comment: yes but by index not by df['SELECTIO'] column names

Comment: thanks your answer and the second answer worked now I am confuse Which one should I accept

Comment: @HabibUrRehman - Hmmm, why oldiest? Unfortunately this is ovecomplicated.

Comment: @HabibUrRehman - But is up to you. In my opinion is better, simplier and faster `df[pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 0], errors='coerce').notna()]`